# querySelectorAll.style does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing something in JavaScript that I need to use `querySelectorAll.style` but it always returns undefined, but it works perfectly with `querySelector.style`.  How can I make it work properly so I can set the style?

```
document.querySelector("div#tabs" + tabId + "> div.page").style.display = 'none'; //works
document.querySelectorAll("div#tabs" + tabId + "> div.page").style.display = 'none';// doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of elements rather than a single one.

So this should work to apply the style to the first element found:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div#tabs" + tabId + "> div.page")[0].style.display = 'none'; // First element
```

Answer (score 8):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> Returns the first element within the document...

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> Returns a list of the elements within the document...

IE in the first one, you're operating on a single element, which does have a `style` property.  The second one is a list of elements, so you need to loop over that list applying the style:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("div#tabs" + tabId + "> div.page");
for (var x = 0; x < els.length; x++)
    els[x].style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 4):

querySelectorAll returns a html collection of elements, not a single element, so you need to loop over the results:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#tabs" + tabId + "> div.page"))
    .forEach(function(val) {
        val.style.display = 'none';
});
```